# Disconnect unwanted Pusher connections

Tags: pusher

I have developed a chat application using Pusher. I want to disconnect all the inactive or unwanted connections so as to avoid crossing the peak limit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll firstly need to identify which connections can be terminated. You could implement this with a timer to determine if a user is inactive or even allow the user to mark themselves as inactive somehow. Once you've done this, you've identified a connection to disconnect. With the Pusher Java client API, it's as simple as calling disconnect().

https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#disconnecting

Hope that helps!